# installing ubuntu 13.04 suddenly gives black screen

Tags: ubuntu, failed-installation

I am trying to install the Ubuntu 13.04,
I have created the boot able device and restarted the system. The system enters the device and showed some options, i have selected the install option and suddenly the display goes blank.

What might be the reason please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may have problems with your graphics card... what's your hardware?

Comment: check out AskUbuntu at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Check your RAM with memtest86, iso coud be downloaded here: http://www.memtest.org/#downiso